# Can't fit image in popup window if image is larger then window

Tags: html, css, image, dom, popupwindow

I'm trying to make a simple centered popup div to show image inside of it. The popup div should have size of image but when image is bigger then page window it is overflow of its parent. I want to set on image max size to window size without using JS.

I'm trying do this, but it is not working, any ideas ?

```css
body {
    color: red;
}

.popup-window {
    padding         : 5px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    display         : inline-block;
    position        : absolute;
    top             : 50%;
    left            : 50%;
    transform       : translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-width       : 100%;
    max-height      : 100%;
}

.popup-window>img {
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>This is the title of the webpage!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="popup-window">
        <img src="https://conpeek.com/test/przod_auta.jpg">
        <!-- <img src="hubspot.png"> -->
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**PROBLEM RESOLVED**

image style should look like this:

```
.popup-window>img {
  max-width: 100vw; 
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

and then when image is smaller then the viewport it have natural dimensions, but when it's bigger then viewport size, it's fitted to viewport correctly.

Answer (score 1):

object-fit contain is a good way to go as you'll ensure the image can be completely seen. But for this to work the img element has to have width and height set (so the system knows what it's trying to contain the image within). Without those settings you just get the image at its natural dimensions.

```css
body {
  color: red;
}

.popup-window {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
 width: 100vw; /* added for demo */
  height: 100vh; /* added */
}

.popup-window>img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>This is the title of the webpage!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="popup-window">
    <img src="https://conpeek.com/test/przod_auta.jpg">
    <!-- <img src="hubspot.png"> -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But in this case, after your change, picture becomes small (I don't understand why it sets on this particular size, why not some bigger or smaller btw). When the image is bigger then page window, I want to wrap it max width and max height to 100% of the page window. Styles like max-width or max-height not work (I guess beaceose parent have no size declared) so this is not satisfying anser for me :(

Comment: If you want the popup to cover the viewport then you can set it to that - I'm not sure I understand what size you want it to be. For now I will change the code so the popup fills the viewport. But are you saying you want that to happen only when the natural dimensions of the image are greater than the viewport, otherwise you want it smaller?

Comment: When the image is smaller then viewport, image should be shown with natural dimensions and parent popup should be in the same size like image (parent fits to child size and have padding space) , but when image is bigger then viewport the popup and image shoud have max 100% (minus padding of parent) size of viewport.

Comment: ok, your change point me to final anser, I should add max-width: 100vw; max-height: 100vh; to image styles and it works as I need to :) I forogot about vw and vh. Thank You ! 
If you want, please change your code and I will mark your answer as a problem solved